# CodeIgniter: How to disable "index.php" in URLs completely (disallow it if manually entered in URL)

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and have been able to use url's without "index.php" in there, but if I manually type in "index.php", the urls still work. I'd like to disable access to "index.php/controller" type urls in order to avoid duplicate content penalty from Google.

Here is what my current .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: The best thing to do is use mod_rewrite or a permanent redirect, but should you not be able to, you can always use Google's `<link rel="canonical" />` tag to tell Google that the page is just another representation of the document at the canonical url. You will not suffer a duplicate content penalty if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by replacing  the last  3 lines with this

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or maybe simply by removing the last line of your .htaccess.

Also you might need to change your /config/config.php to

```
 $config['index_page'] = “”
```

Answer (score -1):

The [CI manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) already gives you an (working) example on how to do it:

> You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some
>   simple rules. Here is an example of
>   such a file, using the "negative"
>   method in which everything is
>   redirected except the specified items:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
> ```
>
> In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for
>   index.php, images, and robots.txt is
>   treated as a request for your
>   index.php file.

Always be sure to check the manual first. It is really good and gives you an easy answer most of the time.

Comment: `In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for *index.php*...` TS wants index.php to be redirected too